# Random Number Generation in Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, random, key

I have 16 million records and need a 8 digit UNIQUE random number for each record, also I want all the numbers to start with 01, and store them in a seperate table, so I can assign the UNIQUE numbers to each record.

I am unsure of how to do this in PHP in order to get 16 million UNIQUE numbers?

Please help?!

J.

Comment: If all of your 8 digit numbers start with 01, you will only have 6 digits left for arbitrary digits. And the number of combinations for 6 digits is only 10^6=1,000,000. So you can not have 16,000,000 unique numbers.

Comment: UPDATE, I mean 16million UNIQUE numbers the same length.

Answer (score 4):

With what you specified, this does not seem possible.

You require **16,000,000** unique numbers from a given **8 digit** number, of which the leading 2 is **01**.

That leaves you with only **6 numbers**, so your range will be **1,000,000** numbers

from **01000000 to 01999999**.

This does not seem correct at all.

Comment: +1. I was thinking very much the same but I wasn't confident in my math skills that my result was correct ;)

Comment: Sorry didnt make it clear 8 digits long and then 01 in front of them, so 10 all together.

Answer (score 1):

John, regarding your comment to pavium, if you need all the numbers to have exactly the same length but not necessarily random you can [make use of the ZEROFILL MySQL property](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) along with the auto_increment index.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: GUID

```
<? 
    echo str_replace ("}","",str_replace("{","",com_create_guid()));
?>
```

Comment: The last time I checked, GUIDs were alpha-numeric and 16 characters long.

Comment: Yah, but at least its unique, maybe he may have a change of thought.. just giving him an option. ü

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to first generate a list of numbers 16M numbers and random sort them and then map each to your record, and it be done in pretty much in PHP native functions.

I have added a stepping loop, so that it doesn't generate a too large array. But it also mean the id will be kinda of look like increamenting, but still random numbers.

Maybe someone can come up with a better solution using rotating string? I am off work now. :)

Comment: Ok cool getting there, the problem is each record in the db will be associated with the number, so needs to read english really and not just 1100000000, so needs to be a mixute of numbers so its readable.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way of generating a **unique** number for each record is to have an auto_incrementing value — so they will be unique, but not random.

.. and they would be generated by MySQL, not PHP. I think it would be a significant overhead to generate 16 million random but distinct numbers in PHP.

Do the numbers *have* to be random? Perhaps uniqueness is a more important requirement?

Comment: Hi pavium, I need all the number to be the same lenght otherwise I would have just autoincremented in the db.

Comment: I thought we were talking about randomness. If the numbers have to be all the 'same length', could we start the auto_increment at a suitable large number, so all numbers have the same number of digits?

Comment: @pavium: I had a similar idea. But maybe he didn't explained himself very well in the comment.

Comment: Ok, I am not the best at all this so your advice is appreciated, when i talk about random I mean basically 16million unique numbers the same length.

Comment: Great, so you could use an auto_incrementing number from 100000000 to 116000000 and they all have the same length.

Comment: Ok cool getting there, the problem is each record in the db will be associated with the number, so needs to read english really and not just 1100000000, so needs to be a mixute of numbers so its readable.

Comment: The plot thickens ... maybe the next step is to display a number as 100 000 000 so it's easy to read out. I know *I* have trouble counting the zeroes in something like 100000000.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of generating the number at random and struggling with keeping track numbers that have been picked, how about generating the number in sequence but update the records in random order?

So, here is a totally MySQL solution. No PHP, no loop, just a batch update statement:

```
UPDATE 
   your_table, 
   (SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 rownum, t.id 
    FROM 
      (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
      (SELECT id FROM your_table ORDER BY RAND()) t
   ) p 
SET unique_num = 100000000 + p.rownum 
WHERE p.id = your_table.id
```

Replace `your_table` with table name, `unique_num` with the column where the unique number will be stored and `id` with the primary key column of your table.

p/s: tested working at least on MySQL 5.1.37

Answer (score 0):

have mysql do it for you:

1. create an auto_increment column
2. add 100000000 using UPDATE
3. done!

if you really need the leading zero, then remove the auto_increment from the column, change it to varchar(10) and prepend a 0 using UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

I like to use a 16-character base-60 varchar for my random primary keys.  Here's a tiny table:

```
mysql> create table foo (k varchar(16), v varchar(255), primary key(k));
```

... and here's some rudimentary PHP, which will hit function k() until it finds an unused key.

```
<?php

require_once 'connect.php';

$v = 'A value that needs a unique random key.';

while (!mysql_query("INSERT INTO foo VALUES ('" . k() . "', '$v')")) {};

function k() {
   $t = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz";
   $r = "";
   for ($i = 0; $i < 16; $i++) {
      $r .= substr($t, rand(0, 59), 1);
   }
   return $r;
}

?>
```

The chances of a collision are small--60 to the 16th--so k() almost never gets called twice. Bonus: if I ever need to make that key larger it's a varchar, so I can add bytes without scragging everything that's already in the table.